# Pressing Alt hangs the application

Tags: winapi

I'm programming a Windows application that doesn't have a menu. Every time I press Alt, it receives the WM_ENTERMENULOOP event and hangs until I press a key.
I've tried other applications without menu (like the MS .chm file viewer) and they exhibit the same behavior.
There is no difference between forwarding the event to DefWindowProc or processing it.

Is there a way to stop Windows from entering the menu loop if there is no menu? Alternatively, is there a way to exit it manually as soon as the event is received?

Comment: You have a menu: The system menu (`WS_SYSMENU`). And the application doesn't hang. The menu loop is pumping messages.

Comment: So it enters the menu loop of the system menu without showing it? That's extremely useful. Guess I'll have to live without the icon. Thanks.

Comment: The system menu will show if you follow the Alt with a space. This "waiting" state is why message boxes sometimes get stuck invisible until you tap the alt key a second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` and `WM_SYSKEYUP` manually (dont' pass them to `DefWindowProc`) if you want to disable entering menu loop.

Also, you may want to process `WM_SYSCHAR` and return `TRUE` for this message to avoiding beeps for keystrokes like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SomeKey</kbd>

Comment: Please don't block Alt+space. It winds me up no end (and I'm sure others) when applications disable standard Windows functionality!

Comment: I didn't block it. I used WM_SYS* messages to make it work without "hanging" everything between Alt and the following keystroke.

Comment: To add, entering a menu loop causes the `WM_ENTERIDLE` message to be sent to the `WindowProc` continually.  Not calling `DefWindowProc` fixes this hang, however, it prevents normal operation (e.g. Alt+F4 doesn't close application anymore).

Comment: Here is a better way to handle this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870103/keep-rendering-a-3d-window-during-modal-dialogs-opening-main-menu/11873217#11873217

Answer (score 1):

Scalable code after parsing window message and return correct result with NO call DefWindowProc.

```
case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
case WM_SYSKEYUP:
case WM_SYSCHAR:
    return (LRESULT)1;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-syskeydown

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-syskeyup

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syschar

> Return value
>
> An application should return zero if it processes this message.

Comment: This could be a great answer Redee! Could you provide a bit of text to help them understand the logic you gave here?