# Keep rendering a 3D window during modal dialogs/opening main menu?

Tags: windows, winapi, 3d, modal-dialog, windows-messages

(I use Ogre3D for the rendering but the question should be generic.)

The problem: most 3D aplications use a cycle which iterates rendering a frame and checking for messages and processing them. However if a dialog is opened (MessageBox or similar), it blocks the execution of the thread and is running it's own message cycle, but it obviously does not call the 3D rendering function in it.

What is the preferred, or "best" way of keeping rendering the 3D scene even when dialogs are open? The normal applications do not suffer from this problem, because their re-rendering is handled by WM_PAINT messages and similar, and since modal dialogs do have internal message loop, the window proc get's called when needed and everything looks fine. In my 3D project however, "when needed" is all the time, because the window has to be updated, even without WM_PAINT messages.

The simple solution that comes to mind is to register a timer for the time when dialogs are open, and render 3D scene from the WindowProc, but is it really the best? Seems very dirty...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that this is the best way, but I think it will work.

Add a handler for [WM_ENTERIDLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that uses [PeekMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do something like:

```
case WM_ENTERIDLE:
    while (!PeekMessage())
    {
        DoYourRendering();
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: `WM_ENTERIDLE` is sent when the dialog/menu is idle (the user is not interacting with it). While the user is interacting, that would prevent the rendering from continuing, which does not meet Cray's requirement.

Comment: I like the elegancy of this solution and it works like a charm with menus, but with MessageBox I don't seem to get the WM_ENTERIDLE message... Argh, looks almost like an error in msdn, it specifically says that this should be sent for dialogs as well... Maybe they mean just custom dialogs...

Comment: @Cray Modal dialogs will send `WM_ENTERIDLE` messages so long as they are *not* created with the [`DS_NOIDLEMSG` style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729172.aspx). I do believe that dialogs created by a call to the `MessageBox` function have this style set by default.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having the code post a custom message to itself when entering the modal operation.  You can then render the current frame when the modal loop dispatches the message, and then post another message to keep a rendering loop running.  Once the modal operation finishes, you can stop posting messages to yourself and go back to your normal rendering logic.  For menus, you can catch the `WM_ENTERMENULOOP` and `WM_EXITMENULOOP` messages to detect when the modal menu message loop begins and ends.

For example:

```
const UINT WM_RENDER_FRAME = WM_USER+100:
```

.

```
BOOL m_InModalOp = FALSE;
```

.

```
case WM_ENTERMENULOOP:
    m_InModalOp = TRUE;
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_RENDER_FRAME, 0, 0);
    break;

case WM_EXITMENULOOP:
    m_InModalOp = FALSE;
    break;

case WM_RENDER_FRAME:
    if (m_InModalOp)
    {
        // render a frame...
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_RENDER_FRAME, 0, 0);
    }
    break;
```

.

```
m_InModalOp = TRUE;
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_RENDER_FRAME, 0, 0);
MessageBox(...);
m_InModalOp = FALSE;
```

Comment: Can you believe it, this doesn't work!!! It starts to render, but application does not respond to any messages anymore. Argh... The interal loop these clowns made probably waits until queue is empty before doing something important... I've even tried using WM_PAINT and WM_TIMER (without a timer) messages, msdn says they have different semantics (only processed after everything else), but to no result. Now I am doing sort of your approach but instead of PostMessage in the loop, I have an extra thread which SendMessage()+Sleep(0) in a loop which ends when m_InModalOp == FALSE

Comment: And that's not all, the described thing works, but for some goddamn reason the fps drops to a pretty exact 1/4th of max when I open the main menu (NOT so with the dialogs)... WTF... So I am using arx's approach (it does not reduce fps...) also for the menus, while this one is used for dialogs which don't produce WM_ENTERIDLE.